# Garbage value is inserting while importing zip file into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, import, import-from-csv

I'm trying to import data through files and below code works fine with csv files but, when I upload a zip file it uploads some garbage value into database. Can you please help me with this. Thank you!

```
<?php

include_once 'dbConfig.php';

if(isset($_POST['importSubmit'])){

$csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet- 
stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');

if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $csvMimes)){
    
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
        
        $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
        
        fgetcsv($csvFile);
        
        while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){
            $name   = $line[0];
            $email  = $line[1];
            
            $prevQuery = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = '".$line[1]."'";
            $prevResult = $db->query($prevQuery);
            
            if($prevResult->num_rows > 0){
                $db->query("UPDATE members SET name = '".$name."', modified = NOW() WHERE email = '".$email."'");
            }else{
                $db->query("INSERT INTO members (name, email) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."')");
            }
        }
        
        fclose($csvFile);
        
        $qstring = '?status=succ';
    }else{
        $qstring = '?status=err';
    }
}else{
    $qstring = '?status=invalid_file';
}
}

header("Location: index1.php".$qstring);

?>
```

Comment: You need to unzip the file first https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Comment: hi @bassxzero but what destination path I should give it for extracted file

Comment: Whatever writable path you have set on you server. Try `/tmp` or check the path that your files are being uploaded to. `echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] `

Comment: Actually you don't have to write the file to storage. You can hold it in memory and iterate through it for your queries.

Comment: thanks for the help @bassxzero but how can I hold it in memory and iterate it?

Comment: now its done. But I'm only able to upload csv files not excel

Comment: Excel files `.xls` are in a different format than `.csv` you will need to use a xls or xlsx file parser to read the file.